# Nativescript Pusher on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, pusher, nativescript-vue

I have successfully configured Pusher on Android which was straight forward.
on iOS, I configured and got a p8 key for APNS. In Pusher dashboard, I entered the key and the Team ID and ran the app on a physical iOS device, subscribed to "hello" interest.
The result of "UIApplication.sharedApplication.registeredForRemoteNotifications" is true which technically means that it had successfully registered for remote notifications but it's not applied on Pusher dashboard, it keeps saying "Waiting For Device".

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm running out of options here :/

Comment: I think this is a query that can be best answered by the Pusher Support team. You can raise a ticket with them over at https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us.

Comment: I already but their response was not helpful

Comment: Are you using any plugin or handling it natively?

Comment: I'm using "@nativescript-pusher/beams" plugin version 2.0.1